# fcm-django add extra params

Tags: django, firebase, django-rest-framework, push-notification

I use drf and fcm-django for pushing notifications to user devices (android/ios) (with firebase)
My Notification model:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, max_length=128)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    message_type = models.CharField(choices=NotificationType.CHOICES, blank=True, null=True, max_length=32)
    link = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()

    unread = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=False,)
```

I need to add extra params "message_type" and "link", something like this:

```
devicesGCM.send_message(body, title=title, type=message_type, link=link)
```

How can I add extra param to notification message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```py
from fcm_django.models import FCMDevice
from yourapp.models import Notification

def send_notification_to_device(notification_id):
    # Fetch the notification
    notification = Notification.objects.get(pk=notification_id)

    # Fetch the user's device
    user_device = FCMDevice.objects.get(user=notification.user)

    # Prepare the extra parameters
    message_type = notification.message_type
    link = notification.link

    # Construct the message with extra params
    data_message = {
        'title': notification.title,
        'body': notification.body,
        'type': message_type,
        'link': link
        # Add any other parameters as needed
    }

    # Send the notification to the device
    user_device.send_message(data=data_message)
```